# Testing with factory girl and basic has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm following this [post on thoughbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl), which I found here searching for the solutions to my problem.

These are the two models:

```
class Admin::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sml, :class_name => "Admin::PostSml", :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sml, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |sml| sml[:fklang].blank? }
end

class Admin::PostSml < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And this is the factory that I'm using for testing it (according to what is described on the blog post):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_post, :class => 'Admin::Post' do
    f_del 0
    published 1

    factory :post_sml do
      after_create do |post|
        create(:admin_post_sml, admin_post: post)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :admin_post_sml, :class => 'Admin::PostSml' do
    post_id 1
    fklang "it"
    title Faker::Lorem.word
    abastract Faker::Lorem.sentences
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraphs
    pub_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
    exp_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
  end

end
```

and the corrisponding model test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::Post do
  it "should create post and sml for post" do
    post = FactoryGirl.create(:post_sml)

    post.should be_valid
  end
end
```

But if I test like this [rspec](/questions/tagged/rspec) gives me the error:

```
Admin::Post should create post and sml for post
 Failure/Error: post = FactoryGirl.create(:post_sml)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `admin_post=' for #<Admin::PostSml:0x007ffbfe7345e0>
 # ./spec/factories/admin_posts.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/admin/post_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

If I test only with `FactoryGirl.create(:admin_post)` on my test log I see the right [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) query for creating the `admin_post` row but not the related `admin_post_sml` row.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Finally i figure out how to make it work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_post, :class => 'Admin::Post' do
    f_del 0
    published 1

    factory :post_with_sml do
      after(:create) do |admin_post|
        create(:admin_post_sml, post: admin_post)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :admin_post_sml, :class => 'Admin::PostSml' do
    fklang "it"
    title Faker::Lorem.sentence
    abstract Faker::Lorem.sentence
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraph
    pub_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
    exp_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
  end

end
```

Comment: `create(:admin_post_sml, post: post)`

Comment: If I do this I've got

_uninitialized constant Post_

Maybe because I've got Admin::Post as model and not only Post

Comment: `factory :post_sml ` that is invalid factory, it refers to `PostSml` class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting factories, you should use traits. You can specify a trait of Post that creates a PostSml with it.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_post, :class => 'Admin::Post' do
    f_del 0
    published 1

    trait :with_sml do
      after(:create) do |admin_post|
        create(:admin_post_sml, post: admin_post)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :admin_post_sml, :class => 'Admin::PostSml' do
    fklang "it"
    title Faker::Lorem.sentence
    abstract Faker::Lorem.sentence
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraph
    pub_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
    exp_date "2014-02-04 09:43:43"
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like this: `create(:admin_post, :with_sml)`